# Not able to run doxygen with python

Tags: python, doxygen

I am trying to learn doxygen by running following Python file.
A similar attempt with c++ file was successful, however i am not able to generate any content in main.html file generated. it is only showing "main page" and "file list" as two links in html page.

What am i doing wrong?

```
""" sample docstring"""
## @package stuff
#  @author me
#  Description
#
#  Some more description

## A class that does whatever
class whatever:
    ## A method that does stuff
    def dostuff(self):
        print 'here'

def show():
    print 'showing'

show()
```

Comment: is there any filter available for python to be read by doxygen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen support for Python was added in version 1.4.4 (http://www.doxygen.nl/changelog_1.4.html). You'll need to update to a more recent version in order to generate doxygen documentation from your Python code.

Comment: Version 1.3.9.1 was released in 2004 (!), so you really should upgrade first

Answer (score 0):

you should try this: `MyClass.E = variable` that is, if I haven't got your meaning wrong.

Comment: I have just copied the code off the doxygen documentation page. I believe thats not an issue here. I have updated the code with a simpler one, still the same issue persists.

Comment: Okay then, sorry you can just ignore my fail. But then it must not be the code problem that produces the error as it's off the documentation page?

Comment: Yes, it's straight off the documentation page. Others have pointed out need to upgrade my doxygen version, let's see if it works then.